# CSS produces a strange space

Tags: html, css, markdown

I use markdown with css, output html sometimes.

But when display in browser, a space prefix to my code segment, only first line. In the pic below, it just before "gconftool".

[image: space prefix]

If I disable css, here is no space anymore. So it really comes from css. Of course I checked html, no space character here.

Below is my css.

```
pre {
    display:block;
/*    overflow:auto;*/
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background-color:#333;
    padding: 0.1em 0.5em 0.1em 0.5em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
/*    border-color: #080;*/
/*    border-style:dotted none;*/
    border-left:0.5em solid #080;
}
code {
    background-color:#333;
    color: #eee;
    font-family: 'Courier 10 Pitch',"Courier New",Monospace;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

So how can I get rid of this space.

append:
I had solved it. thanks jsfiddle.net, thanks all.

Comment: share a working fiddle or full code?

Comment: you need full css? may be it too long to paste.

Comment: Is there a possibility to check if it works when you remove the indentation in your code for pre tags only ?

Comment: Please share CSS + HTML, you could use a tool like this to share: http://fiddlesalad.com/css/, https://jsfiddle.net/, http://www.bootply.com/new

Comment: Please provide all of your code, I don't get any spacing from left, see for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly0429yr/

Comment: Maybe there is non-printable character that is converted to space?

Comment: @Gijsberts There is in-site resource - SO Snippet that can be used directly in question/answer

Comment: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/-c2ioGH1TJ5yP1s1aY~WbV5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=  html   https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/y6N0ZAvbz85x0436t7YPeF5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE= css

Comment: @Justinas Thanks, nice to know :)

Comment: I paste full html and css above.

Comment: @Justinas not strange character in html.

Comment: jsfiddle.net can debug. good. seems it comes from other part of the css. But I can not found the error.

Comment: @utopiceexpress is your website live somewhere ? a staging link may be?

Comment: @Gijsberts thanks. I found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `margin` and `padding` here:

```
em,strong,code {
    margin: 0px 0.2em 0px 0.2em;
    padding: 0px 0.4em 0px 0.4em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Are they there for any need? Because when I remove those two your spacing is gone. Below a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ly0429yr/2/

Comment: Sorry If I am missing something. Wasn't the space never there itself ? What is gone now ?